# Windows Task Scheduler Console access to Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, scheduled-tasks, kubernetes-pod

so I have created some scheduled tasks to run in a windows kubernetes pod but I would like to connect to this pod via Windows Task Scheduler console.

I have opened ports 135 and 49154 on the load balancer to the pod, enabled the administrator account on the pod with a new password but I am getting an error of "You do not have permission to access this computer"

Is there an additional step that I am missing?

Comment: Can you describe your environment in more details? How did you deploy your cluster? Is it in cloud/ on-prem? Windows/ Linux nodes?

Comment: it is in AKS, windows nodes.